# Question on usage of XML with XPath vs XML as Class

Tags: c#, xml

I have few XML files which I would be using in my C# code.

So far I have been using XPATH for accessing the XML node / attributes

Question is what advantage would I get if i convert the XML to Class file (XSD.EXE) and use it in terms of maintainability and code readability.

In both the cases I know if I add or remove some nodes, code needs to be changed

In my case the DLL goes into GAC.

I am just trying to get your views

Cheers,
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of converting your XML to XSD and then to a C# class is the ease in which you can grab yet another file. Your code would be something like:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
FileStream fstm = new FileStream(@"C:\mysample.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

MyClass result = ser.Deserialize(fstm) as MyClass;

if(result != null)
{
  // do whatever you want with your new class instance!
}
```

With these few lines, you now have an object that represent exactly what your XML contained, and you can access its properties as properties on the object instance - much easier than doing lots of complicated XPath queries into your XML, in my opinion.

Also, thanks to the fact you now have a XSD, you can also easily **validate** incoming XML files to make sure they actually do correspond to the contract defined - which causes less constant error-checking in your code (you don't have to check after each XPath to see whether there's any node(s) that actually match that expression etc.).

Comment: thanks for your comment. how exactly can I validate the xml in case of XML as class? with exception type throwm?

Comment: @In this code sample, you'll get an exception when you try to call `ser.Deserialize` which will tell you the source XML file doesn't conform to the XSD